# Rooting Nexus 7 - SuperSU Binary Update Installation Failed

Tags: rooting, nexus-7, superuser

Can someone please help me find the correct SU binary for this device? I am trying to install the SU binary for SuperSU, and I get an installation failed every time.

I have been looking for information on this specific problem, and from what I have read, I may have to download a new binary file and download it through flash recovery (shrug). I thought I would try that, but I cannot find anywhere with information specific to my device.

If you think the problem could be caused by something else, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated SuperSu from the google play store, and now I am getting the following error:

"There is no SU binary installed, and SuperSU cannot install it."

This seems to confirm that I do need to install the SU binary for my device version, but I still not found where I can find the SU binary.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to download the latest SuperSU from [Chainfire](http://download.chainfire.eu/370/).  Push that to your Nexus 7 using adb push and install it from your custom recovery.  I'm guessing you have that already?

Comment: Yes, I just installed "UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.93.zip", and I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Do you have a terminal emulator on your device?

Comment: I can download one, if that would help some how.

Answer (score 1):

After having the 'no SuperSU Binary' error message I followed this guide :
[How to Root Nexus 7 2012 (Wi-Fi) and Nexus 10 on Stock Android 5.0 Lollipop via CF Auto Root](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-root-nexus-7-2012-wi-fi-nexus-10-stock-android-5-0-lollipop-via-cf-auto-root-1474771)
that worked after several attempts.   most importantly  I had to be in the stock rom ( lollipop)  then run the root-windows command.  then  while it says  "waiting for device", I the switched tablet off, then  vol down+power to go into bootloader. Then the magic happened.

hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://download.chainfire.eu/310/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.04.zip). Install the SU Binaries from here than update to latest version.

Hope this helps.